# What does "Aren't allocating the things put into queues" mean?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm reading this:

https://concurrency.markmail.org/search/?q=ArrayBlockingQueue+LinkedBlockingQueue#query:ArrayBlockingQueue%20LinkedBlockingQueue%20from%3A%22Doug%20Lea%22+page:1+mid:sgx3amdfga7esqul+state:results

In which Doug Lea says:

> Usually, when you are putting something into a queue, you will have
> just allocated that new something.  And similarly, when you take
> something out you usually use it and then let it become garbage.  In
> which case the extra allocation for a queue node is not going to make
> much difference in overall GC, so you might as well go for the better
> scalability of LinkedBlockingQueue. I think this is the most common
> use case.
>
> But, if you aren't allocating the things put into queues, and don't
> expect lots of threads to be contending when the queue is neither
> empty nor full, then ArrayBlockingQueue is likely to work better.

I want to know what does `Aren't allocating the things put into queues` mean?

Also, this sentence: `don't expect lots of threads to be contending when the queue is neither empty nor full, then ArrayBlockingQueue is likely to work better`, can someone explain that a little bit more specifically?

Comment: From the context it seems to mean if the things you put in the queue are long-lived, i.e. someone has already allocated them a long time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me that seems to mean following:

1. > I want to know what does `Aren't allocating the things put into queues` mean?

   This is about the GC overhead which they discus.

   `LinkedBlockingQueue` creates [new internal `Node` object](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17+0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#L123) for every added item, which means it generates garbage and, as a result, causes garbage collection (GC).
   Doug says that often the items we store in a queue are objects which:

   - are created right before they are added to the queue
   - become unused (and eligible for GC) shortly after they are removed from the queue

   In these cases the items themselves cause GC anyway, therefore it's not a problem that `Node` objects require GC as well.

   But if you only store long-lived objects in a queue, then `LinkedBlockingQueue` might become the only thing that causes GC.
   Then you might want to use `ArrayBlockingQueue` instead to avoid GC.
   (`ArrayBlockingQueue` doesn't create any objects when items added/removed)
2. > Also, this sentence: `don't expect lots of threads to be contending when the queue is neither empty nor full, then ArrayBlockingQueue is likely to work better`, can someone explain that a little bit more specifically?

   `LinkedBlockingQueue` [uses two locks](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17+0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#L86): one for `put()` and one for `take()`.
   `ArrayBlockingQueue` [uses one lock](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17+0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#L121) for both `put()` and `take()`.
   As a result when "`the queue is neither empty nor full`" (i.e. when neither `put()` nor `take()` have to wait) and there are two threads: one executes `put()`, another one executes `take()`

   - if the queue is `LinkedBlockingQueue`, then the threads don't block each other
   - if the queue is `ArrayBlockingQueue`, then one thread will have to wait until the other one is done

Comment: Well said. The one thing possibly confusing the OP is what type of long lived objects that Doug Lea is referring to.